# Does semantic-release support integration with Jenkins CI?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, semantic-release

I was looking at [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) and was wondering if semantic-release support integration with Jenkins CI?

When I looked at [CI configuration](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/caribou/docs/usage/ci-configuration.md#ci-configuration), I could not find any configuration details for Jenkins.

Can anyone please share valuable information on this?

Answer (score 0):

semantic-release uses [env-ci](https://github.com/pvdlg/env-ci) to read CI provided environment variables and Jenkins is supported.
As a general information semantic-release uses the CI environment variables to determine:
- if the current execution is happening on a CI
- the current branch being built
- if the current build was triggered by a Pull Request

So any CI for which the `branch` property is provided by [env-ci](https://github.com/pvdlg/env-ci) is supported. If the `isPr` property is not provided, semantic-release will always consider the build wasn't triggered by a Pull Request.